# Duplicate ViewController in other ViewControllers containing the mainViewController as subViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

I am developing a game, but I am having difficulty solving this issue and to make it easier to see my idea I will create an image of how I want it to function.

[image]

Basically have the game split into multiple views (multitouch) as they choose different difficulty, and then putting it in multiple viewcontrollers but duplicating the mainViewGame.

I want to know how I can do this and keeping each copy fully functional.

Comment: do you mean you want to have the exact same view multiple times, or that you want multiple instances of the same view controller to display their views?

Comment: i want multiple instances of the same view controller to display their views, for example lets say that the mainViewGame is a guy running and you have to click for him to jump over a block. I want to have that put into the hardViewGame twice at a 50/50 screen size so now you have to play with 2 guys jumping rather then one, and so on and so forth. Here is an app that has a the concept: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/no-one-dies/id866965413?mt=8  @simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you probably want view containment.

Create a container view controller that just has a view in it's nib.

Then create an instance of your game view controller, and add it as a child view controller of your container.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    GameViewController *topGameViewController = [[GameViewController alloc] init];
    GameViewController *bottomViewController = [[GameViewController alloc] init];

    topGameViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds) / 2);
    bottomGameViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds) / 2, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds) / 2);

    [self addChildViewController:topGameViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:topGameViewController.view];
    [topGameViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    [self addChildViewController:bottomGameViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:bottomGameViewController.view];
    [bottomGameViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];  
}
```

Code untested - is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I am sorta new to Objective-C so, let me test out this code and see how it goes @simon

Comment: I am having trouble implementing this :/ @simon